# How do I combine two arrays, one as a key and the other as an array?

Tags: php

The output of the first array as the value for the update in the third array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 1
                    [3] => 1
                    [4] => 1
                    [5] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [4] => 0
                    [5] => 1
                )

        )
```

The output of the second array as a key for updating the third array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
        )
```

This is the third array with 48 keys

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 1
    [10] => Array
        (
            [4] => 1
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [4] => 1
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [4] => 1
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [5] => 1
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [5] => 1
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [6] => 1
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [6] => 1
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [7] => 1
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [7] => 1
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [8] => 1
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [8] => 1
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [9] => 1
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [10] => 1
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [10] => 1
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [11] => 1
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [11] => 1
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [12] => 1
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [12] => 1
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [13] => 1
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [13] => 1
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [14] => 1
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [15] => 1
        )

    [45] => Array
        (
            [15] => 1
        )

    [46] => Array
        (
            [16] => 1
        )

    [47] => Array
        (
            [16] => 1
        )

    [48] => Array
        (
            [16] => 1
        )
```

The problem is that I can not use one as a key and the other as a value to update the third array

***Code I have tried :***

```
foreach($arraykey as $key => $value){
    for ($i=0;$i < count($array3) ; $i++){
        if ($value2==$i){
        $array3[$value2]=$arrayval[0][0][$i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You question is unclear in terms of what desired output you want form all those three arrays?

Comment: Please share more details - did you try anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_combine()`, for example like this:

```
<?php
   $a = [1,2,3,4];
   $b = [4,5,6,7];
   $c = array_combine($b,$a);
   print_r($c);
?>
```

result:

```
Array (
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 4 )
```

Comment: I have a problem with this function. When combining, I put exactly the first two arrays, but I had no output

Comment: Yes, my problem will be solved if I enable this function

Comment: Since the answer solved your problem, you might want to consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).